# Making models.py for Django Rest Framework Primary key and foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I made a models like this :

```
from django.db import models
import json

# Create your models here.
class Data(models.Model):
node_id = models.ForeignKey("Node", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
vibration = models.IntegerField()
moisture = models.IntegerField()
gps_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
gps_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
gyro_x = models.FloatField()
gyro_y = models.FloatField()
gyro_z = models.FloatField()
accelero_x = models.FloatField()
accelero_y = models.FloatField()
accelero_z = models.FloatField()
displacement = models.IntegerField()


class Node(models.Model):
node_id = models.IntegerField()
latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
lokasi = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

The Data models have endpoint at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/
And Node models have endpoint at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/node/
I want the node_id in Node class to become a primary key and the node_id from Data class to become a foreign key.
I try to post to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/node/ like this :

```
    {
    "node_id": 1,
    "latitude": "123",
    "longitude": "123",
    "lokasi": "eer"
}
```

And then I open the endpoint for Data models at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/data/ to post some data.
On the Node id field, it should be referring to node_id=1, but why it just referring to node object(8) which is the id that generates automatically from Django rest framework? [image: API Data models]

It makes the post data look like this:

```
{
"id": 13,
"timestamp": "2020-04-14T20:00:00+07:00",
"vibration": 1,
"moisture": 1,
"gps_latitude": "123",
"gps_longitude": "123",
"gyro_x": 1.0,
"gyro_y": 1.0,
"gyro_z": 1.0,
"accelero_x": 1.0,
"accelero_y": 1.0,
"accelero_z": 1.0,
"displacement": 1,
"node_id": 8}
```

The "node_id": should be 1 not 8.
Is there any wrong with my models?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are using custom primary key to rename it to `node_id` instead of `id` ?

Comment: yes, i don't use id as primary key. the id is generate from system by it self, i don't do anything to id

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the relation, which I supposed is 1:N (Node:Data)

So if you'd rewrite your models to:

```py
class Node(models.Model):
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lokasi = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lokasi


class Data(models.Model):
    node_id = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name="data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    vibration = models.IntegerField()
    moisture = models.IntegerField()
    gps_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gps_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    gyro_x = models.FloatField()
    gyro_y = models.FloatField()
    gyro_z = models.FloatField()
    accelero_x = models.FloatField()
    accelero_y = models.FloatField()
    accelero_z = models.FloatField()
    displacement = models.IntegerField()
```

So now you can assign Node by id when creating Data model, and vice versa you can assign collection of data objects from Node by calling

```
Node.objects.first().data.all()
```

Ad: *why it just referring to node object(8)*

You need to add a `__str__` method which will tell Django how to interpret your object when casted to string, so I added a example into your Node class

Node will have `id` field as Autogenerated Primary key and `node_id` as ForeignKey to `Node`

Comment: where I put this : Node.objects.first().data.all()   ?

Comment: I still need to post node_id on Node class. And then that node_id become primary key on Data class

Comment: Wherever in the django app, you can tinker with this when running `python manage.py shell`

Comment: I am sorry I still need the node_id on Node class. And after that the node_id in Node class became primary key on Data class. How to do that?

Comment: You have the node's ID, it is its PrimaryKey, called `id`. ForeignKey is for assigning existing records from given table using its ID, you want to add data from a node, so that node needs to exist. If you your goal is to just post Data objects and automatically create the nodes when it does not exists yet, you would need to override the save method of the object and do that manually

Comment: instead of id, how to make node_id to become primary key?

Comment: node_id is foreignkey to node, why would you want to use it as primary key aswell that does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to design the back end for a GPS system, I would recommend checking https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis & https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ first & having a solid grasp on Django models & query API. this is not exactly a fix for your question but more of a high-level suggestion after checking your codes and other related comments on the thread. These will help you develop GIS API more easily.